# Switching from one-unit IRF to one-standard-deviation

Tags: econometrics

I'm manually calculating the IRF of a VARX. I calculated the IRF to a unit-shock to the independent variable. Now I want to switch to a one-standard-deviation shock.

Do I multiply the resulting one-unit shock IRFs by the standard deviation of the shocked (independent) variable?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a baseline regression equation,
$$y=\beta_0 +\beta_1 x+u$$
$\beta_1$ is "the average change in $y$ that is associated with $x$ increasing by 1".

Thus, $\sigma_x\cdot \beta_1$ is "the average change in $y$ that is associted with $x$ increasing by $\sigma_x$.

I believe this logic applies to IRF of VARX, so I think the answer to your question is "yes". However, I am not a macro guy and don't use those tools at all, so if someone else has a contradictory answer, they are probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

One way to estimate the effect of a one-standard deviation shock is to standardize your shock variable. I don't know which program you are currently using, however in R the function standardize() in the package datawizard produce the correct standardization ! I also think that Michael answer is true !